# Android API to detect Samsung Galaxy Camera Zoom Buttons

Tags: android, zooming

in Android, is there any API to detect when the "zoom hardware button" of devices such as the "Samsung Galaxy Camera" is pressed? If its a Key press, then which one would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a key press, with key codes KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ZOOM_IN and KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ZOOM_OUT.